# Generalized likelihood ratio test for a left-truncated exponential distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference, likelihood-ratio, truncated-distributions

I am doing self study in statistical inference and am rather confused about how to approach generalized likelihood ratio test (GLRT) problems.  I am trying the traditional approach by definition and running into a wall.

**Problem:**

Let $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be independent and identically distributed observations from the exponential distribution on the interval $(a, \infty)$ with the scale parameter $b>0$ with PDF:

$$
f(x) = \dfrac{1}{b} \exp \left(\dfrac{x - a}{-b}\right) \cdot I\left(x > a\right)
$$

Find the generalized likelihood ratio test of level $\alpha$ for testing $H_0 : a \leq c$ vs. $H_1 : a > c$ for a given constant $c$.

**Attempt:**

My understanding of GLRT problems is that we first need to find the test statistic $\lambda(x) = \frac{\sup_{H_0} L(\theta | x)}{\sup_{H_0 \cup H_1} L(\theta | x)}$.  To find get the supremum of the likelihood $L(\theta | x)$, we can do so by using the MLE.

The likelihood where $b$ is known is:

$$
L(a | x) = \dfrac{1}{b^n} \exp\left(\dfrac{-\sum x_i + na}{-b}\right)\cdot I(x_{(1)} > a)
$$

In the case of the problem, the MLE for parameter $a$ is $x_{(1)}$, the first order statistic since that value is the only one that can maximize the likelihood.

This is the point of the problem where I get a rather lost since I do not know what to do with the "less-than" part of the null hypothesis.  The test statistic when $H_0 : a = c$ is:

$$
\lambda(x) = \dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{-\sum x_i + nc}{-b}\right)\cdot I(x_{(1)} > c)}{\exp\left(\dfrac{-\sum x_i + na}{-b}\right)\cdot I(x_{(1)} > a)} = \exp\left(\dfrac{n(c - a)}{-b}\right)\cdot \dfrac{I(x_{(1)} > c)}{I(x_{(1)} > a)}
$$

**Note:** This problem is rather similar to [Likelihood ratio test for two-parameter exponential distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521089/likelihood-ratio-test-for-two-parameter-exponential-distribution) however, in this problem we are dealing with the truncation parameter.  In addition, I do not believe the approach in that post applies to this problem and if it does, I am not sure how to replicate it.

Comment: Small note: A left truncated exponential is more commonly called a *shifted* exponential, and sometimes a two-parameter exponential (I don't like the latter term though because it's ambiguous, indeed other distributions get called by the same name). Your truncation parameter is the shift parameter. There are a number of posts about this distribution

Comment: @ThomasLumley I am not sure I understand what you're getting at.  This kind of sounds like a restatement of what I already wrote out :(

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you, I will take a look.  It seems that https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/377786/what-should-my-critical-region-look-like-in-this-lr-test-for-shifted-exponential is the same problem.